# Q factor for an LRC series circuit

Tags: filter, frequency, impedance

Trying to prove to myself that the Q factor for an LRC series circuit is \$\sqrt{L/C}/R\$, but I am struggling with it...

My reasoning runs that the half power upper frequency limit is (ignoring the \$2\pi\$ factor) R/L, so half the frequency delta is \$R/L-1/(\sqrt{LC})\$ and the full bandwidth (assuming symmetry) at half-power is \$2(R/L-1/\sqrt{LC})\$

Then given \$Q=f_{res}/BW\$, we have \$Q = (1/\sqrt{LC})/(2(R/L - 1/\sqrt{LC}))\$,

which can be simplified to \$L/(2(R\sqrt{LC} - L))\$ which is similar to the correct answer, but not correct, with an errant factor of 2 and a stray -L kicking around.

Where has my reasoning gone wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The resonant frequency is the *geometric* mean of the upper and lower half power frequencies, not the *arithmetic* mean you seem to be using here.

\$\omega_0 = \sqrt{\omega_l \omega_h} \ne \dfrac{\omega_l + \omega_h}{2}\$

That's probably all you need but here's some additional information just in case.

[UPDATE:  upon further reflection, there's something else you need.  The relationship between Q and BW you are using is a high-Q *approximation*.  Deriving the genuine Q from this approximation requires a bit more than I've given below.]

For a series RLC, we have:

\$ Z = \dfrac{1 + j \omega RC - \omega^2LC}{j \omega C}\$

The numerator is of the form:

\$ 1 + j\frac{1}{Q} \frac{\omega}{\omega_0} - (\frac{\omega}{\omega_0})^2\$

Comparing these two forms, see that:

\$ \omega_0 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{LC}}\$

\$ Q = \dfrac{\sqrt{\frac{L}{C}}}{R}\$

How to see that the resonant frequency is the geometric mean?

Consider the product of two first order functions:

\$ (1 + j\dfrac{\omega}{\omega_l})(1 + j\dfrac{\omega}{\omega_h}) = 1 + j \omega (\dfrac{1}{\omega_l} + \dfrac{1}{\omega_h}) - \dfrac{\omega^2}{\omega_l \omega_h}\$

From this, we deduce:

\$\omega_0 = \sqrt{\omega_l \omega_h}\$

\$ Q \omega_0 = \omega_l || \omega_h =\dfrac{1}{\dfrac{1}{\omega_l} + \dfrac{1}{\omega_h}} \rightarrow Q = \dfrac{\omega_0}{\omega_l + \omega_h}\$

Comment: I thought your point about the geometric mean would make it clear so i accepted the answer, but I am still at a loss. I don't understand what the Z in the above answer represents - or rather how you have derived it. If Z = \$\sqrt{R^2 + (X_L - X_C)^2}\$ - how does that relate to what you have here?

Comment: Great!  I knew you'd see it!